# SQLDMO.SQLServer: "A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed."

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, sqldmo

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the following piece of code running and am at a loss as to why it isn't working:

VBS Script:

```
On Error Resume Next

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Start")

Dim oServer
Set oServer = CreateObject("SQLDMO.SQLServer")
oServer.LoginSecure = True
oServer.Connect "(local)"

If (Err.number <> 0) Then
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Failed to connect to server (" & Err.number & ")"
    Err.Clear
    WScript.Quit(-1)
End If
```

Error Popup:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Runtime Error!

Program: C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe

R6034

An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.


---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Console Output:

```
C:\Users\mryan\Documents\Code\script>cscript tfes_migrate.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Start
Failed to connect to server (424)
```

I have installed the SQLServer2005 Backwards compatibility pack.

Any ideas would be appreciated!